# Can I boost/improve reception on my Droid?

Tags: network-signal

With a rooted phone and an app you can overclock or underclock your processor.  Also, off Android, with some hacks you can boost power of a wifi router and wifi antenna.  It seems to me that if you can do those things you could boost the reception of your cell antenna some how.  Am I right?  If so, how?

Comment: Put your droid in a can? ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a telecom engineer student, I know that one of the main limitation for power is the EIRP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_isotropically_radiated_power).

Overpassing the EIRP is one of the must known way to increase wifi router power (by adding a better antenna, which leads to an increase in gain, and in power RX/TX). This power is perhaps fixed by the software in Android handsets, and you could use this parameter to leverage the emission power.

But, as far as I know it's illegal (at least in France).

Answer (score 1):

Not really to do with actually altering your reception per-se, but you can update your PRL (preferred roaming list) of your phone for newer cell towers which might give you better reception.  On Verizon, dial `*228` and follow the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

updating your radio may help (if there is update for your phone).
after some search its seems there is.

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL: you can brick your phone flashing your radio if do not know what you are doing

Comment: ...and I don't know what I'm doing, but luckily I knew that before bricking anything.